# Copying and merging directories excluding certain extensions

Tags: python, windows, copy-paste

I want to copy multiple directories with identical structure (subdirectories have the same names) but different contents into a third location and merge them. At the same time, i want to ignore certain file extensions and not copy them.

---

I found that the first task alone can be easily handled by `copy_tree()` function from the `distutils.dir_util` library. The issue here is that the `copy_tree()` cannot ignore files; it simply copies everything..

> distutils.dir_util.copy_tree() - example

```
dirs_to_copy = [r'J:\Data\Folder_A', r'J:\Data\Folder_B']
destination_dir = r'J:\Data\DestinationFolder'
for files in dirs_to_copy:
    distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(files, destination_dir)
    # succeeds in merging sub-directories but copies everything.
    # Due to time constrains, this is not an option.
```

---

For the second task (copying with the option of excluding files) there is the `copytree()` function from the `shutil` library this time. The problem with that now is that it cannot merge folders since the destination directory must not exist..

> shutil.copytree() - example

```
dirs_to_copy = [r'J:\Data\Folder_A', r'J:\Data\Folder_B']
destination_dir = r'J:\Data\DestinationFolder'
for files in dirs_to_copy:
    shutil.copytree(files, destination_dir, ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns("*.abc"))
    # successfully ignores files with "abc" extensions but fails 
    # at the second iteration since "Destination" folder exists..
```

Is there something that provides the best of both worlds or do i have to code this myself?

Comment: How about tweaking the [shutil copytree example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#copytree-example) so that it ignores duplicate directories by catching the error from `makedirs`?

Comment: @PeterBrittain But if i do that, it will skip the folders entirely right? And, I do need their contents.

Comment: No it won't.  It will try to make all the folders, hit an exception (which you swallow with a new try...except hander around that one line) and then move on to the directory walk (copying files or recursing as needed).

Comment: Thanks for the hint (distutils.dir_util>copy_tree()). I have the same issue as your first one I am using copy_tree(). The problem is some files have the same name. Do you know how can copy and rename file names like os operation (name(1) or name_1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As **PeterBrittain** suggested, writing my own version of `shutil.copytree()` was the way to go. Below is the code. Note that the only difference is the wrapping of the `os.makedirs()` in an `if` block.

```
from shutil import copy2, copystat, Error, ignore_patterns
import os


def copytree_multi(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    names = os.listdir(src)
    if ignore is not None:
        ignored_names = ignore(src, names)
    else:
        ignored_names = set()

    # -------- E D I T --------
    # os.path.isdir(dst)
    if not os.path.isdir(dst):
        os.makedirs(dst)
    # -------- E D I T --------

    errors = []
    for name in names:
        if name in ignored_names:
            continue
        srcname = os.path.join(src, name)
        dstname = os.path.join(dst, name)
        try:
            if symlinks and os.path.islink(srcname):
                linkto = os.readlink(srcname)
                os.symlink(linkto, dstname)
            elif os.path.isdir(srcname):
                copytree_multi(srcname, dstname, symlinks, ignore)
            else:
                copy2(srcname, dstname)
        except (IOError, os.error) as why:
            errors.append((srcname, dstname, str(why)))
        except Error as err:
            errors.extend(err.args[0])
    try:
        copystat(src, dst)
    except WindowsError:
        pass
    except OSError as why:
        errors.extend((src, dst, str(why)))
    if errors:
        raise Error(errors)
```

Answer (score 2):

For those finding this now:

`shutil.copytree()` now has a `dirs_exist_ok` argument as of Python 3.8. Together with the [`ignore_patterns` argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.ignore_patterns), this can now accomplish merging two directories to a third location in one line:

```py
from shutil import copytree, ignore_patterns

for source in dirs_to_merge:
    copytree(source, destination, dirs_exist_ok=True, ignore=ignore_patterns('*.pyc', '*.txt'))
```

For example, to exclude files that end in `.pyc` or `.txt` (tweaked from docs).

Answer (score 0):

if you do want to use shutil directly, here's a hot patch for os.makedirs to skip the error.

```
import os
os_makedirs = os.makedirs
def safe_makedirs(name, mode=0777):
    if not os.path.exists(name):
        os_makedirs(name, mode)
os.makedirs = safe_makedirs

import shutil

dirs_to_copy = [r'J:\Data\Folder_A', r'J:\Data\Folder_B']
destination_dir = r'J:\Data\DestinationFolder'
if os.path.exists(destination_dir):
    shutil.rmtree(destination_dir)
for files in dirs_to_copy:
    shutil.copytree(files, destination_dir, ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns("*.abc")) code here
```

Comment: But upon executing `shutil.rmtree(destination_dir)` i am going to be removing its contents too which will be coming from a directory that will not be copied again. At the end i am going to end up with a copy of the last directory on the `dirs_to_copy` list and everything else would have been copied and then deleted.